# Is the contents of a pointer to a unique_ptr's contents valid after the unique_ptr is moved?

Tags: c++, pointers, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I've been led to understand that calling a member function on the contents of a moved-from `std::unique_ptr` is undefined behaviour. My question is: if I call `.get()` on a unique_ptr and *then* move it, will the original `.get()` pointer continue to point to the contents of the original unique pointer?

In other words,

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a = ...
A* a_ptr = a.get();
std::unique_ptr<A> a2 = std::move(a);
// Does *a_ptr == *a2?
```

I think it does, but I want to make sure.

('contents' is probably the wrong word. I mean the data you get when you dereference the pointer)

Comment: The object behind that pointer isn't destroyed. And the address of an object cannot change. Thus the address you have must still be valid.

Comment: @drescherjm No, after the move, the first unique_ptr doesn't own anything.

Comment: I see now. I mistakenly thought that a_ptr was used in the move (which did not make sense to me - got to read carefully).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merely moving the `unique_ptr` only changes the ownership on the pointed-to object, but does not invalidate (delete) it. The pointer pointed to by `unique_ptr<>::get()` will be valid as long as it hasn't been deleted. It will be deleted, for example, by the destructor of an owning `unique_ptr<>`. Thus:

```
obj*ptr = nullptr;                          // an observing pointer
{ 
  std::unique_ptr<obj> p1;
  {
    std::unique_ptr<obj> p2(new obj);       // p2 is owner
    ptr = p2.get();                         // ptr is copy of contents of p2
    /* ... */                               // ptr is valid 
    p1 = std::move(p2);                     // p1 becomes new owner
    /* ... */                               // ptr is valid but p2-> is not
  }                                         // p2 destroyed: no effect on ptr
  /* ... */                                 // ptr still valid
}                                           // p1 destroyed: object deleted
/* ... */                                   // ptr invalid!
```

Of course, you must never try to use a `unique_ptr` that has been moved from, because *a moved-from `unique_ptr` has no contents*. Thus

```
std::unique_ptr<obj> p1(new obj);
std::unique_ptr<obj> p2 = std::move(p1);
p1->call_member();                          // undefined behaviour
```

Comment: Should we extend the caveat that one must not use the raw pointer of a `unique_ptr` which is moved as well since the entity which received the moved pointer could possibly destroy it?

Comment: @Zoso Storing the pointer returned by `unique_ptr::get()` for later usage is a bad idea anyway (moving the `unique_ptr` is not the only way to invalidate the stored pointer).